# Why EF does not show EntityState as Added for new entities added in-memory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please refer to below code snippet:

```
using (var entities = new SchoolDBEntities())
        {
            ////entities.Students.Add(new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "New Student1" });
            Student newStudent = entities.Students.Create();
            newStudent.StudentID = 5;
            newStudent.StudentName = "New Student1";
            entities.Students.Add(newStudent);

            Student studentToRemove =  entities.Students.Find(1);
            entities.Students.Remove(studentToRemove);

            // Perform a query against the database.
            Console.WriteLine("\nIn DbSet query: ");
            foreach (var student in entities.Students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found {0}: {1} with state {2}",
                                  student.StudentID, student.StudentName,
                                  entities.Entry(student).State);
            }
        }
```

**Note: There is no SaveChanges called yet.**

Questions -

1. On the output console, I do not see new entity "New Student1" with state as Added. Why?
2. If the DBSet only shows the data which is in DB, why does the in-memory change of removing the student **shows up in the console with state as Deleted**?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the student you added the same as the student you deleted?

Comment: I see your point. Please refer to edited code. Still same result. No Added State displayed on the console.

Comment: What is the output of the program?

Answer (score 3):

That's because `entities.Students` only returns the entities that are currently present in the database.

If you list the entities that are currently tracked ...

```
foreach (Student student in entities.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(e => e.Entity))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0}: {1} with state {2}",
                      student.StudentID, student.StudentName,
                      entities.Entry(student).State);
}
```

... you also see the new entity.

By the way, `entities.Students.Local` displays all entities that are currently "visible" locally. It shows the new student, but not the deleted one.

Comment: Ok, This helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because there was no SaveChanges yet. You can use the `Local` property:

```
foreach (var student in entities.Students.Local)
```